# How to use methods and call them within the Switch statement

Tags: java

I'm making a tax calculator for class but I can't quite figure out how to separate my code in my individual cases

```
  println("Please enter your filing status: ");
    println("Enter 0 for single filers,");
    println("      1 for married filing jointly,");
    println("      2 for married filing separately, or");
    println("      3 for head of household");
    double tax = 0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    int filingStatus = readInt("Status: ");
    switch (filingStatus) {
        case 0: double taxableIncomes = readDouble("Please enter your taxable income: ");
        if (taxableIncomes <= 8925)
        {
            tax = (taxableIncomes * TEN);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }
        if (taxableIncomes > 8925 && taxableIncomes <= 36250)
        {    
            tax = 892.5 + FIFTEEN * (taxableIncomes - 8925);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }
        if (taxableIncomes > 36250 && taxableIncomes <= 87850)
        {
            tax = 892.5 + 4098.75 + TWENTYFIVE * (taxableIncomes - 36250);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }
        if (taxableIncomes > 87850 && taxableIncomes <= 183250)
        {
            tax = 892.5 + 4098.75 + 12900 + TWENTYEIGHT * (taxableIncomes - 87850);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }
        if (taxableIncomes > 183250 && taxableIncomes <= 398350)
        {
            tax = 892.5 + 4098.75 + 12900 + 26712 + THIRTYTHREE * (taxableIncomes - 183250);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }
        if (taxableIncomes > 398350 && taxableIncomes <= 400000)
        {
            tax = 892.5 + 4098.75 + 12900 + 26712 + 70983 + THIRTYFIVE * (taxableIncomes - 183250);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }
        if (taxableIncomes > 400000)
        {
            tax = 892.5 + 4098.75 + 12900 + 26712 + 70983 + 577.5 + THIRTYNINE * (taxableIncomes - 183250);
            println("You owe: $" + df.format(tax));
        }   
        break;
```

into separate methods then call the methods under case:0.  For my calculator i'm supposed to use four separate methods and since I have four separate cases I figured the easing thing to do was sort the code for each case into different methods then call those methods for each case that I have.  If I try to use

```
private double tax()
```

and copy and paste all of the code from under case 0: it tells me that class,interface, or enum expected.

Comment: "class,interface, or enum expected" is a syntax error.  Don't confuse that with how to structure your code.  Start by making it compile - understanding and fixing each error you get.  Then figure out how to structure it better and add the rest of your functionality.

Comment: I have the program working fine for each case with 0 compile errors.  It only stops working when I try and move my code into different methods then call them under each case.

Comment: Same thing applies.  You need to figure out what "stops working" means and fix whatever that is.

Comment: What would be the best way for me to separate each case into separate methods? I've tried using a private method for tax using taxableIncomes as a parameter but I can't return tax at the end of that method because it keeps telling me "cannot find variable tax" and I think that's because tax is defined within each if statement.  How can I return tax so that it recognizes the variable tax determined by the if statements which depend on taxableIncomes

Comment: I wrote my other header like this

     private double tax(double taxableIncomes)

and I used 

     double tax = tax(taxableIncomes)

to call the method under case: 0 but it kept telling me that it cannot find the variable tax

Comment: Sorry man, I can't teach you a Java course via SO comments.  You're gonna have to dig into the basic syntax yourself and work through it.